# Deploying spring web apps using Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

I'm new to Java web framework, I googled to find that spring is one of the most popular framework. I tried to install tools and searched a tutorial to run spring framework on my mac.

#### step 1  - Tomcat installation

Following [this site](http://neilang.com/entries/how-to-install-tomcat-on-mac-os-x/), I could install Tomcat on my mac. I'm using :8080 port for Tomcat.

#### step 2 - spring tool suite installation

From [this site](http://www.springsource.org/spring-tool-suite-download), I could install Spring Tool Suite.

#### step 3 - making an example following tutorial

I [found a tutorial](http://manueljordan.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/creating-a-spring-web-mvc-project-with-springsource-tool-suite/) on using Spring Tool Suite. Following the procedure, I could build manolitomvc app.

[image]

#### step 4.1 - deployment <-- issue 1

Finally, I'd like to access the web app at `http://localhost:8080/manolitomvc`.

I clicked the green arrow to see the error message.

[image]
[image]

#### step 4.2 - deployment <-- issue 2

I opened overview page, and I guessed that I could set server location and deploy path to make spring web app available.

However, I have no idea how to set the server location (Tomcat server location that I installed in step1).

[image]

I tried to copy the manolitomvc directory into Tomcat main document directory(`/Library/Tomcat/webapps`), but it doesn't work.

How can I deploy the web app so that I can access the spring web app at `http://localhost:8080/manolitomvc`?

Could you recommend any other practical tutorial that I can follow to setup and use spring framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to use "VMware TC" try to start with a "normal" Tomcat.

- Open the Context Menu in the "Servers" tab:  New/Server
- Select Apache/Tomcat v? -> Next
- Select The Tomcat Intallation Directory, or click on "Download and Install.."

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Ralph's help, I could make Tomcat server working Spring Tool Suite.

### Step1. Stop the tomcat server

`cd  /Library/Tomcat/bin` and execute `sudo sh shutdown.sh`.

### Step2. Create server

From Servers, New > Other ...

[image]

Select server/Server

[image]

Select Apache/Tomcat

[image]

Select web application

[image]

### Step3. Execution and test

Execute the server

[image]

You can access the app through `localhost:8080/manolitomvc`.

[image]