# Making Spring Tool Suite generated web app work on standalone Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web-config

From [Deploying spring web apps using Spring Tool Suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444096/deploying-spring-web-apps-using-spring-tool-suite/12448586#12448586) question, I could build and deploy spring web application with Spring Tool Suite. I could access the app at `localhost:8080/manolitomvc`.

[image]

Shutting down the Spring Tool Suite Tomcat server, I relaunch Tomcat with `sudo startup.sh`, but I got this error message.

[image]

What's wrong? What server setup is necessary for making `manolitomvc`  app to work?

### ADDED/SOLVED

Based on Ralph's answer, I could make it work.

In STS workspace directory, I could generate the war file in Tomcat directory.

[image]

Copying the war file in the web apps make the deployment work. Interestingly, the `manolitomvc` directory is generated automatically with the action of copying.

[image]

Or, you can just set the destination to the webapp directory.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STS/Eclipse use a complete different (lets call it) "working directory" for tomcat.

If you want to run your application without STS/Eclipse, than let STS/Eclipse or Mave create a war file for your project.

- for maven it is: `mvn package` - it creates a war file in the target folder
- for STS+Maven it is: Project/Run as.../Maven Package
- for Eclipse without Maven: Project/Export/Web/WAR file

Then you need to copy this war file into the `webapps` folder of your ORIGINAL tomcat installation (NOT the folder `.metadata/plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core...` within your eclipse workspace direcory)

Comment: The war file is an special archive (at least a zip) that contains the complete application so that it can be deployed on the server. Its filename is MyApplication.war @see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_%28Sun%29

Comment: Thanks, I just copied the war file and everything works fine.

Comment: That is exactly what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

For the app to run outside of STS or to generate a deployable `.war` file install maven on your computer and add the below to your pom.xml

pom.xml:

`<packaging>war</packaging>` preferable at the beginning under the `<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>` reference.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

at the very end of your file, this will add the maven plugin to your project.

Once Maven is installed, you can navigate to your project within you terminal `cd /path/to/project` and run `mvn install` this will generate a `.war` file with having a `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` added to your app name, you can rename and drop the war file anywhere you run your server.